# Recursive question missing multiplication

Tags: java

I have this recursive code

```
 public static int m(int n1, int n2) {
        int result;   
   if (n2 - n1 == 0) {          
result = n1;      }
 else {
            int mid = (n1 + n2) / 2;
            result = m(n1, mid) * m(mid + 1, n2);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

but i dont understand why the second part of recursive multiplication is not execute , if i enter a parameters (2,3) the results is 6 but in my calculation below is 120

```
              
                m(2,3)
              mid= 5+2=3
         m(2,3)   *    m(4,5)    
     mid= 2+3/2=2     mid= 4+5/2=4
   m(2,2) * m(3,3)    m(4,4)  * m(5,5)
     
      2     *   3         4   *   5
                  6 * 20
                     120
```

could you explain me why  thanks

Comment: sorry i just confuse (2,3) enter with (2,5 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may appear confusing at first (and you can of course modify as you see fit), but sometimes it helps to:

- print out variables as they are modified.
- break up recursive calls on the same line to print out intermediate results.

```
public static int m(int n1, int n2) {
    System.out.printf("%nMethod entered: n1 = %d  n2 = %d%n", n1, n2);
    int result;
    int firstCall;
    int secondCall;
    if (n2 - n1 == 0) {
        result = n1;
    } else {
        int mid = (n1 + n2) / 2;
        System.out.printf("mid = %d%n", mid);
        System.out.printf("firstCall =  m(n1 = %d, mid %d)%n", n1,mid);
        firstCall = m(n1, mid);
        System.out.printf("secondCall = m(mid+1 = %d, n2 = %d)%n",mid+1,n2);
        secondCall = m(mid+1,n2);
        System.out.printf("result = firstCall{%d} * secondCall{%d}%n", firstCall, secondCall);
        result = firstCall * secondCall;
        System.out.printf("result = %d%n", result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

When run with m(2,5) it prints

```
Method entered: n1 = 2  n2 = 3
mid = 2
firstCall =  m(n1 = 2, mid 2)

Method entered: n1 = 2  n2 = 2
secondCall = m(mid+1 = 3, n2 = 3)

Method entered: n1 = 3  n2 = 3
result = firstCall{2} * secondCall{3}
result = 6
secondCall = m(mid+1 = 4, n2 = 5)

Method entered: n1 = 4  n2 = 5
mid = 4
firstCall =  m(n1 = 4, mid 4)

Method entered: n1 = 4  n2 = 4
secondCall = m(mid+1 = 5, n2 = 5)

Method entered: n1 = 5  n2 = 5
result = firstCall{4} * secondCall{5}
result = 20
result = firstCall{6} * secondCall{20}
result = 120
120
```

Comment: No it doesn't.  In both methods m(2,5) gives 120.  m(2,3) gives 6.  As I said in an earlier comment, the second  call of me will not happen until the first one returns.

Comment: yeah sorry i just confuse it , thanks alot it really helpful split recursion in that way . Would you racommend to read something in order to improve recursion skills?

Comment: It just takes some time to get use to it.  Try some things and if you don't understand you can always ask here.  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68090838/java-recursion-simple-string/68092221#68092221) is a question also regarding recursion.  Some of the answers may be helpful.  There are other examples on this site too.  Search using the `recursion` tag.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're calculating the mid wrong in the first step. The correct recursion tree would be -

```
            m(2,3)
          mid = 2 [=5/2] 
     m(2,2)   *    m(3,3)    
        2     *       3         
              = 6
```

Comment: yea thats the left part  m(n1, mid)  but why is skip the right part ? m(mid + 1, n2)

Comment: The right part will first be called when the first call of the left part returns.  That's why it helps to split them to see what is going on.